# GameObjected "sucked" into another GameObject effect while dragging

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am building a chemistry game where the user can drag around different atoms and connect them together to build molecules.  I am able to get the atoms to "stick" to one another when they collide.  However, the spheres are stuck just on the outside of each other.  I want to get them to overlap slightly like the picture below.

[image]

Basically, I want the user to click and drag the mouse to drag atom spheres within the radius of other atom spheres.  When that collision happens, I want the atom to be "sucked" into the other atom.  However, the problem I am facing is that because the user is holding on to the atom with the mouse, any sort of movement is negated.  I've tried each of the three lines of code below but none of them work in getting that atom to suck into the other one while the user is holding the mouse.

```
atom_entering.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(atom_entering.transform.position, this_atom.transform.position, 5*Time.deltaTime);

atom_entering.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MovePosition(this_atom.transform.position + (atom_entering.transform.position - this_atom.transform.position));

atom_entering.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(this_atom.transform.position, ForceMode.Acceleration);
```

If I try to decrease the radius of each atom, it can work but then the atom starts clipping any other collisions like the table itself.

Edit: Asked to post complete code:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    GameObject atom_entering = collision.gameObject;
    GameObject this_atom = this.gameObject;

    if(atom_entering.name == "HydrogenPrefab(Clone)" && num_hydrogens < max_hydrogens && !hydrogen_connected)
    {
        // Code to make the "suction" effect here
        // One of the three lines above went here but none of them worked.

        // First, make the hydrogen a child of this oxygen atom.
        // Next, create a Fixed Joint component on the hydrogen and stick it to the oxygen
        atom_entering.transform.parent = this_atom.transform;
        atom_entering.AddComponent<FixedJoint>();
        atom_entering.GetComponent<FixedJoint>().connectedBody = this_atom.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        atom_entering.GetComponent<HydrogenCollider>().setConnectedStatus(true);

        // Increment the number of hydrogens connected to the oxygen
        num_hydrogens += 1;

    }
}
```

In a separate C# script:

```
void OnMouseDrag()
{
    this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    RaycastHit hit;
    if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Camera.main.farClipPlane))
    {
        float oldY = this.transform.position.y;
        this.transform.position = new Vector3(hit.point.x, oldY, hit.point.z);
    }
    this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
}
```

Edit: Here is a video of how it is currently behaving.  https://vimeo.com/185896832

I want that same behavior expect I just want to get it "sucked into" the parent atom.  If I do anything with the radius, the atoms sink into the floor a bit which is not what I want.  It doesn't make sense to have an object with a normal radius when it interacts with the floor and a different radius when it interacts with an atom.

Comment: post your complete code

Comment: Perhaps shrinking the collider area to a less radius may give you the same effect.

Comment: No offense, but horrible approach and your app will end up a mess. As of your question, if you plan to do something "big", use states for the GOs the user can manipulate or has any effect on the user (Idle, Bonding, InBond, etc), otherwise use a bool (isBonding) or even more hacky, check if the item has a joint on it. If the status is not OK for dragging, return; or start dragging the parent GO or whatever logic/behaviour you want

Comment: @NeverHopeless My question stated why decreasing the radius doesn't quite give me what I want.  It starts sinking into any other collisions (e.g. the desk, other atoms that don't bond)

Comment: @Mark Since posting this question, I began implementing certain 'states' tough I called mine "isConnected" but I like your nomenclature better.  However, I'm still trying to figure out how to get that "suction" behavior where the atom can look like the picture above without decreasing the radius.

Comment: Can you post a picture of what is happening now? You only have a picture of what you expect to happen

Comment: @noblerare, you can detect the type of object with the atom was collided. if it is an atom instead of a table you go inside bonding logic or simply ignore it otherwise.

Comment: @NeverHopeless, I tried your suggestion and it didn't quite work.  Even if I modify the radius of the atoms after it detects a collision, the atoms are just touching on the outside and now the atom sinks into the ground a little just as expected...

Comment: @Programmer, perhaps a video may be easier.  I edited the original post.

Comment: I don't think you understand my question. I see what is going on now. What do you expect to happen to the ball if this is not the effect you want?

Comment: @Programmer, What I want is some sort of radius around the red sphere where if the white sphere enters that radius while the player is mouse down and dragging it, it gets "sucked" into the red sphere and stuck there such that it looks like the picture above.  Right now I can only get the radius and "stuck there" part working but not the "suction" effect while the user is dragging the mouse.

Comment: What I would suggest would be using another approach : correct me if I'm wrong but from I remember from my old chemisty class, H atoms are precisely located around O one when forming a H2O molecule (this taken as an example). You could define placeholder Transforms on your O atom prefab that will serve as reference localPosition : this way, when you detect the colision you simply have to place the H atom in one of the free spots around the O atom ? (if you don't want to place those placeholders manually you could use a mathematical approach to automatically generate them on Start())

Comment: @Kardux, yes that sounds like what I want.  I haven't heard of that before and I've been trying to find some resources online but have had no luck.  Can you point me in the right direction or write an answer to this question?

Comment: Is the script above attached to every molecule or some. If you can update the question with complete script and where they are attached, I will replicate your problem then provide you with an solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well here's how I would do it :

- I would create prefabs of my **atoms** with empty *GameObjects* as children serving as references (example : OxygenAtom => HydrogenPos1, HydrogenPos2, HydrogenPos3 and HydrogenPos4)
- On atoms I would have a script managing the available position and occupied ones
- When the atom you're carrying (let's say **Atom2**) collides with another atom (**Atom1**), you check the available positions for one that fits the **Atom2** type.
- If it fits, you tag the available position as occupied and parent **Atom2** as child of **Atom1** and finally place him at the position you just checked as occupied.

**EDIT :** here's a sample of code to bind atoms together :

```
protected void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if(gameObject.name.Equals("Oxygen") && collision.gameObject.name.Equals("Hydrogen"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Binding...");
        StartCoroutine(BindAtomAfterFixedUpdate(collision.gameObject));
    }
}

private IEnumerator BindAtomAfterFixedUpdate(GameObject atomToBind)
{
    GetComponent<SphereCollider>().isTrigger = true;
    // or GetComponent<SphereCollider>().enabled = false;
    yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
    atomToBind.transform.position = transform.FindChild("HydrogenSpot").position;
    gameObject.AddComponent<FixedJoint>().connectedBody = atomToBind.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    GetComponent<SphereCollider>().isTrigger = false;
    // or GetComponent<SphereCollider>().enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: This strategy makes sense but what I am trying to figure out is the part of actually positioning the child atoms onto the parent atom.  Is this done as part of the prefab where I can use these empty GameObjects as "location hotspots" (for lack of a better term) and then just plug in an atom at that location when it collides?  Are rigidbodies even allowed to be "within" another rigidbody?  I still want collisions to be able to occur so turning of rigidbodies won't really work for me.

Comment: I don't think you need to turn off rigidbodies : they are allowed to be "within" eachother as long as you use `FixedJoint`. What you may need to do is to create and destroy the `FixedJoint` components on the fly when a colision happens. Be aware that you need to set the child atoms position before setting the `FixedJoint` (otherwise you may experience strange physic behaviours ^^).